# How to use enter instead of a button JTextArea?

Tags: java

For some kind of messenger application I am using a JTextArea so I can type in multiple lines. But after looking at the documentation I see there is no action event handler for this.

How can I enter text and when I press ENTER it shows up in a other text area?
I wish to use no buttons for this

Regards.

Comment: Something for consideration: You have a conflict in your requirements. On the one hand, you want to be able to type multiple lines, OTOH, you want ENTER to do a submit.  So if ENTER is to submit your message for sending, how will you cause a newline to be created in your text area, in a way that is not surprising to the user?

Answer (score 4):

The default Action when you use the Enter key is to add a "new line" string to the Document. If you don't like this behaviour then you need to replace this Action with your own custom Action.

Read up on [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) to see how you might do this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to hook a listener to key-change event raised by this control? I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

// JTextArea  txASend
   // JTextArea  txAReceive 
   // add the event "KeyTyped" to txASend

private void txASendKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

```
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {
        String msj = txASend.getText();
        txAReceive.setText(msj);
    }

}
```